Remove multiple blank lines in text as a form
I have created this little Flask app. Here the user can insert a text into a form and it should output the same text, only that multiple blank lines should be removed. The logic re.sub(‘\n\n+’, ‘\n\n>’, input_text) works in Python but not for HTML with re.sub(‘\n\n+’, ‘<br><br>’, input_text).
Where is the problem?
App.py:

from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import TextAreaField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
import re

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'ehhfkdfhdf'

class KeyForm(FlaskForm):
    text = TextAreaField('Paste text', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def main():
    form = KeyForm()
    
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        input_text = form.text.data
        consecutive_newlines = re.findall('\n+', input_text)
        
        if len(consecutive_newlines) > 2:
            input_text = re.sub('\n\n+', '<br><br>', input_text)
        
        return render_template('index.html', form=form, result=input_text)
    
    else:
        return render_template('index.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


HTML:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Startseite</title>
</head>
<body>


<form action="" method="post">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

    <p>
        {{ form.text.label }} <br>
        {{ form.text() }}
    </p>
    <p>
        {{ form.submit() }}
    </p>
</form>

<h3>Result:</h3>
{{ result }}

</body>
</html>


The form should output the same text, only that multiple blank lines should be removed

Please [edit] your post to include the exact result, as well as the exact intended result. Perhaps with multiple examples

Why do you even need to check that there are 3+ groups of newlines before substituting? Are you sure you only want to substitute if there are 3 separate newline groups?

maybe first use regex to reduce \n and later use standard .replace() to replace them with <br> ?

The following example removes all empty lines. To display the text as sent it uses a pre element. This makes replacing with <br> unnecessary.
When removing empty lines, also take into account the appearance of carriage return characters.
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template, 
    request 
)
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField, TextAreaField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
import re 

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your secret here'

class KeyForm(FlaskForm):
    text = TextAreaField('Paste text', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = KeyForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        text = re.sub(r'\r?\n(?=\r?\n)+', r'', form.text.data)
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form method="post">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
                {{ form.text.label() }}
                {{ form.text(rows=16) }}
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 0.3rem">
                {{ form.submit() }}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    {% if text -%}
    <div>
        <h3>Result:</h3>
        <pre style="border: 1px solid #000; padding: 0.2em;">{{ text }}</pre>
    </div>
    {% endif -%}
</body>
</html>

